# Storing a counter-flow chiller

Tags: storage, wort-chiller

I just got a counter-flow chiller put together and have used it a couple times. Needs some tweaks, but man it really chilled the wort!

After I was done I ran some hot water through it and tried to drain it as best as I could. I was wondering what the best way to possibly store the chiller for a couple of weeks would be so I don't get any weird growth or something inside? Any thoughts?

- Is blowing it out good enough?
- Can I keep starsan in it and just cap the ends? Is that bad for the copper?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do with a counter flow chiller is to make sure it is clean and drained completely before storage.  I will usually run boiling water through the chiller to clean but you can also use PBW as long as you rinse it with warm water.  Blowing it out with an air compressor will help drain the rest of the water.
You don't want to store it with cleaner of sanitizer as this can cause pitting or degradation of the metal whether it stainless steel or copper.
Back flushing or a thorough cleaning before the next use after storage on occasion will help maintain the cleanliness.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am still debating how I feel about the counter-flow chiller. Maybe I should get a pump to make the cleaning process easier. Thanks again.